# Select Múltiple MySQL

Tags: select, mysql-workbench

Qué tal,

Tengo 4 tablas relacionadas, de las cuáles necesito hacer una consulta.
Tablas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero consultar por Carrera cuántos alumnos hay en cada semestre, algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo la siguiente consulta, la cuál me arroga el semestre en el que está cada alumno: Sin embargo la carrera que me indica está mal, NO es la carrera a la que pertenece.

```
SELECT idProgram, idAlum, MAX(Semestre)as Semestre FROM Alumno, Materia a
INNER JOIN Historial n ON a.idMateria = n.claveMateria 
GROUP BY idAlum;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano, Gracias.

Comment: idProgra es el codigo de la carrera?

Comment: Así es, es la clave de la carrera.